# How to get the original MAC address of a network card, after the OS modified it?

Tags: networking, ethernet

How can I find out the original MAC address for a network card, after it was modified by the OS? dmesg doesn't provide it, and the logs in /var/log too, and dmidecode doesn't provide it too and ethtool. What remains? A custom script?

Comment: Have you tried [MACChanger](https://github.com/alobbs/macchanger)?

Comment: How can I get the original MAC with macchanger?

Comment: According to the [ArchWiki on Spoofing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing), which is where I found the idea, try `macchanger -p interface` while the device is in the down status.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

This will give you the actual MAC address of the device.  Look for the `serial:` entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely find it in the system logs (please search better) or, as last resource, you could try to lookup the router DHCP logs (although this might not be possible in your unknown scenario).

Comment: I was just hoping that if the OS changes the MAC after the device is recognized, the original MAC could be found somewhere

Comment: Yes, this is true but not for all devices. For example embedded devices can have an integrated ethernet controller that basically has no MAC set in hardware, and comes up with any MAC that software driver will tell it to use.

Answer (score 0):

If

- you are using Linux *and*
- your NIC is handled by a removable kernel module *and*
- you can bring the NIC down for a while

then unloading and reloading the kernel module should reload the the MAC as well. With a  bit of care (and luck) it can be done even remotely (obviously one has to put the commands on one line or into a script), but if the spoofing was there for a reason, it might be a good idea to make sure the MAC gets changed to the same spoofed address when the NIC goes live again.

However, it really should be in the kernel log.

Answer (score 0):

(late to the game, supplemental answer for `systemd-networkd` users for completeness)

if using `systemd-networkd` you can `networkctl status <IFACE>`

If it has been spoofed by `teamd` you will see 2 lines

```
Hardware Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:3c:02
Permanent Hardware Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:3c:03
```

where it wasn't spoofed you will only see the `Hardware Address` line

Answer (score 0):

`ethtool --show-permaddr <device name>` should always show the permanent MAC, and is not dependent on having high-level tools like `lshw` installed.